# VBA (o excel)Filtrar por número de semana en una tabla

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy intentando encontrar una manera de poner un autofiltro en una tabla de excel.
Por defecto puedo poner los filtro de semana actual, pasada y siguiente.

Pero lo que quiero hacer ahora es que pueda coger el número de la semana de una celda y filtrar el campo fecha de la tabla por ese número de semana.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontré esto, que me sirve:

- Con el número del año y de la semana, calculo el primer y último día de la misma.
  Seguramente descuadre un poco a final e inicio de año.

  ```
  nYear = shdict.Cells(2, "C")
  nWeek = shdict.Cells(4, "C")

  inputDate = DateSerial(nYear, 1, 1)
  inputDate = DateAdd("ww", nWeek - 1, inputDate)
  wd = Weekday(inputDate, vbMonday)

  StartDate = DateAdd("d", 1 - wd, inputDate)
  LastDate = StartDate + 7
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una columna auxiliar y utilizar las funciones:

```
=NUM.DE.SEMANA(A3)
```

O bien

```
=ISO.NUM.DE.SEMANA(A3)
```

Y aplicar filtros utilizando esa nueva columna. Obviamente la celda A3 contiene una fecha.